# LSTM input shape for spectrogram data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, spectrogram

I have got a numpy array shaped like `n x t x f` where n is the number of spectrograms, t the time samples and f the frequency samples.

This is the code:

```
print(train.shape) # this would print (4431,399,101)

inputs = Input(shape=(399, 101))

encoded = LSTM(50, 
               activation="relu", 
               return_sequences=True)(inputs)
encoded = LSTM(25, 
               activation="relu", 
               return_sequences=False)(encoded)

decoded = RepeatVector(399)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(50, 
               activation="relu", 
               return_sequences=True)(decoded)
decoded = LSTM(25, 
               return_sequences=True)(decoded)

autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                    loss='mse',  
                    metrics=['acc'])

autoencoder.fit(train, train_labels, epochs=20, batch_size=32)
```

It raises:

> InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32,399,101] vs. [32,1]
> [[node gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined
> at :1) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_7304]

I suppose the error is in the input shape, but I don't understand the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your model input expecting two dimensional array and your input array is reflecting three dimensions. I guess.

Comment: LSTM models need a 3D input (batch_size, time_samples, features). Batch size is set by the fit model which is basically the number of spectrograms (training samples) utilised in one training iteration, time samples are 399 and then frequency should be considered as features.
So I don't really understand what's going wrong

Comment: unfortunately without looking into data starting from input import and complete workflow, I cannot comment.

Comment: I uploaded a reduced version of the dataset (first ten samples) on Drive: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1weoejD1Qg1fuqfFye38e11ubILzKHix6/view). It can be loaded as train to have the same affect. As regards labels, you can just do train_labels=np.array(range(10))